# .NET Excel AutoFilter - Error: Cannot invoke a non-delegate type

Tags: c#, .net, excel

Below is code that was converted from VB.NET to C#. It was used to filter Excel rows (2016 definitely worked) with a certain color. After conversion, I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Cannot invoke a non-delegate type. Stacktrace:    at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Int32 )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
```

The error occurs at range.Autofilter...:

```
oWS.AutoFilterMode = false;
Range range = oWS.Range["A1", oWS.Cells[rowCount]];
range.AutoFilter(Field: 1, Criteria1: oWB.Colors(6), Operator: XlAutoFilterOperator.xlFilterCellColor);
```

I have searched a number of message boards and haven't come across this issue, and have no idea where to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
oWB.Colors[6]
```

otherwise it looks like you're calling a method named `Colors`